# Show() , Hide() doesnot performs for all conditions in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on a website where user can take up quizzes. Now each quiz has 20 questions, three sections where 1markx10questions, 2marksx5questions, 4marksx5questions. I have listed 4 radio options for each question and with that one radio showing 'I do not want to attempt' and one checkbox that is for 'Review' which comes after a user has clicked one of the answer's option. Now when user again clicks on 'I do not want to appear' the 'Revision' checkbox disappears. Now the issue is this whole process is happening only for the first question and this 'Review' button doesn't appears at all for rest of the questions in the quiz. 
Here is my code for that,

```
<li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
      <div class="radio noMargin">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="<?php echo $no ; ?>"  name="optionAns<?php echo $i ; ?>"  value="<?php echo $rowO['id'] ; ?>">
          <?php echo $rowO['options'] ; ?></label>
      </div>
    </li>
<?php } ?> 


   <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
      <div class="radio noMargin">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="<?php echo $no ; ?>" accesskey="notAttempt" checked name="optionAns<?php echo $i ; ?>"  value="NA">
          <p style="color:red;">I am not Attempting this question</p></label>
      </div>
    </li>



<li class="list-group-item">
<div class="wrp_review">
      <div class="radio noMargin  bg-danger">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkedInfo" alt="<?php echo $no ; ?>" accesskey="revision" name="optionAnss<?php echo $i ; ?>"  id="optionAns<?php echo $no  ; ?>" value="NA">
          Revision</label>
      </div>
      </div>
    </li>                
        </ul>        
<?php $i++;$no++; ?>
<?php $sectionOne++;} ?>
```

The above sent code is being repeated thrice for three sections.
Now the jQuery that I have applied,

```
$('.wrp_review').hide();
$('.wrp_radio input[type="radio"]').click(function(){

if($(this).val()=="NA"){

  $(this).closest('ul').find('.wrp_review').hide();

  $(this).closest('ul').find('.wrp_review input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
 }else{

 $(this).closest('ul').find('.wrp_review').show();  
 }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solved. Found the classes for all the buttons were not properly called. Hence solved.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to lack of simple condition check, bcos you are checking if the value equals "NA" hide revision box else show it. Better can you please debug in the browser by placing `debugger;` statement so you can confirm yourself that there is no flaw in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the time spared. As you referred using `debugger;` , I did that but still it does not shows any error. Can something else be done